# "Edit" column in CMS block grid (Row id in `_prepareColumns()` )

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to create a column with "Edit" hyperlink to open the row in a new page.

I have created the column like this:

```
$this->addColumn('action_edit', array(
        'header'   => 'edit',
        'width'    => 15,
        'sortable' => false,
        'filter'   => false,
        'type'     => 'action',
        'actions'  => array(
            array(
                'url'     => $link,
                'caption' => 'edit',
            ),
        )
    ));
```

But I do not know how to get the correct url to replace the `$link` with.
I know I want the same link that already exists as the row "title", but I can't figure out how to get it programmatically.

Also, just getting the row id would solve my issue I believe.

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshot how you want the edit button?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I know how to create the button itself, but the functionality is not working... (but I edited the question so you know what I mean)

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code instead of yours:

```
$this->addColumn('action',
    array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
        'width'     => '50px',
        'type'      => 'action',
        'getter'     => 'getBlockId',
        'actions'   => array(
            array(
                'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'),
                'url'     => array(
                    'base'=>'*/*/edit',
                    'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                ),
                'target'=>'_blank',
                'field'   => 'block_id'
            )
        ),
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'index'     => 'stores',
));
```

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Sorry about the follow-up, but what would I put in the `getter` for "catalog price rules" grid?

Comment: Not understand. What do you mean ?

Comment: `getBlockId` will get the Id of the `CMS->Static Blocks` grid row, but what if I want to get the Id of a `Promotions -> Catalog Price Rules` grid row?

Comment: That is different grid rather than cms blocks. Can you post new question

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/233455/51693