# “Edit” column in `Promotions->Catalog Price Rules`

Tags: magento-1.9

To add an "Edit" column for `CMS->Static Blocks` I can use:

```
  $this->addColumn('action',
    array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
        'width'     => '50px',
        'type'      => 'action',
        'getter'     => 'getBlockId',
        'actions'   => array(
            array(
                'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'),
                'url'     => array(
                    'base'=>'*/*/edit',
                    'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                ),
                'field'   => 'block_id'
            )
        ),
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'index'     => 'stores',
    ));
```

But now I want to do the same thing for `Promotions->Catalog Price Rule` and `Promotions-> Shopping Cart Price Rules` grids.

I probably just have to change the `getBlockId` to something else but I don't know how to find the correct function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code for **Catalog Price rules**:

```
$this->addColumn('action', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Action'),
    'width'     => '50px',
    'type'      => 'action',
    'getter'     => 'getId',
    'actions'   => array(
        array(
            'caption' => Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Edit'),
            'url'     => array(
                'base'=>'*/*/edit',
                'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
            ),
            'field'   => 'id'
        )
    ),
    'filter'    => false,
    'sortable'  => false,
    'index'     => 'stores',
));
```

Use the below code for **Shopping Cart Price rules**:

```
$this->addColumn('action', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Action'),
    'width'     => '50px',
    'type'      => 'action',
    'getter'     => 'getId',
    'actions'   => array(
        array(
            'caption' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Edit'),
            'url'     => array(
                'base'=>'*/*/edit',
                'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
            ),
            'field'   => 'id'
        )
    ),
    'filter'    => false,
    'sortable'  => false,
    'index'     => 'stores',
));
```

Comment: You welcome.  :)